# Hash function programming

Tags: hash

I have program for a hash function:

```
 H(a || b || g || y1 || y2)
```

where a,b,g,y1,and y2 are inputs. Can anybody tell me what to do with these inputs if I am using `SHA-2` as my hash function? does this mean I have to either concatenate all the inputs, do the OR operation, or something else??

Comment: Are you using hash for security checks or for lookup of some sort?

Comment: using hash for security check means check the integrity of the message

Answer (score 1):

You can xor them, if these inputs are numbers, or concatenate them using sentinels, if they are strings.